# Global/WebService identifiers cannot be removed from managed application

Tags: apex, managed-package, package

I am getting the following error when I saving the updated file in managed package org.

> Global/WebService identifiers cannot be removed from managed application

Please Help me,How to do the changes in class ,it is not allowing me to save the class.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, you can't remove global access items. You can, however, add the [@deprecated](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_deprecated.htm) annotation to tell users not to use that member because it is no longer supported. You must still *include* those items, but they will no longer appear in the code for new installs. If you're using the Force.com IDE, right-click on the file and Force.com / Synchronize to determine which code you must keep.

Comment: "webService methods and variables cannot be deprecated." https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_deprecated.htm